# Execute python file with input in c#

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, command

I want to execute my python file with c#.
my python file is

```py
    challenge = get_challenge()
    if challenge is True:
        action = input("Send Email Or Sms")
        if action == "Email":
            send_email()
        elif action == "Sms":
            send_sms()
    else:
        username = input("Enter Username")
        save_username()
```

What should I do in c# ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible run python in .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222459/is-it-possible-run-python-in-net-application)

Comment: I think IronPython use only for python 2.7. I use python 3.7

Comment: You might be right, sorry. My mistake!