# C#/MAUI IronPython

Tags: python, c#, android, maui, ironpython

How to use IronPython in MAUI, I need to be able to use IronPython to work with the port, but I can't figure out where to put the python file, and if I use

```
dynamic python = Execute("import numpy")
```

in which I use numpy, it throws the error "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'"

I tried to put the python file in bin/debug/"platform" but nothing worked

Ultimately, I want this to work on android.

Comment: You can check this answer about [How to run python in .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22222756/19335715).